# Background image center and resize

Tags: html, layout, css

I'm working on a site for a client in which there's a background image that will be centered on the page with text, links, etc. overlayed.

I currently have the image resized as follows:

```
img.bg
   {
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   }
```

This fits the image to the height of the browser, but aligns it to the left. I need it to be centered.

Since I need it to be conditionally responsive to browser-height variations, the usual centering tricks aren't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "position:absolute" and adding margin: 0 auto. For example:

```
img.bg
{
   height:100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: when I do that, the image simply sizes itself back to its original HUGE size.

Answer (score 0):

or may be just place it inside a table `<table align="center"> <tr><td>"image goes here"</td></tr>` it's easier to manage cause you can add more items to the webpage in future without difficulty, add borders, change colours of tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple ways to go about it (untested, so you'll probably have to tweak):

```
img.bg {
   position: absolute;
   /* Top and/or bottom for stretching it vertically as needed. Setting both will likely make it the size of the whole body, so beware. Remove bottom to keep it from doing that if necessary. */
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   /* Left and/or right for sizing/positioning */
   left: 25%; /* Percentage position will make it adjust to browser window size, exact percent may need to be tweaked to get right and will depend on the image's size. */
}


img.bg {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 500px; /* Whatever your desired width is. */
   margin: 0 auto; /* This should work as long as width is set. */
}
```

Depending on your exact design, either of these should work and be responsive to the size of the browser window. The second one is probably the most flexible and easiest to implement, since you don't have to fiddle with positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on exactly what you are after.

If you want an image displayed in the background of the website (which I think you are saying) then I am not sure what method you are using, but if you do away with your `img.bg{}` in your html and css, and just put the following into your CSS you will get what you want...

```
body{
    background-image:url('background.gif'); // substitute background.gif for the correct file path
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:auto 100%;
}
```